# how to use Multiple attribute in StaticResource(uwp)?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

How to use multiple key(used in ResourceDictionary) in Style="{StaticResource

TopHeader }"

Answer (score 1):

You can combile your multiple styles inside new created style.
For example:

```
    <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Style2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Style1Style2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
```

or you can create BasedOn style:

```
   <Style x:Key="Style3" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style2}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: can we write Style="{StaticResource  Style1 Style2}" similar to html css

Comment: I thing there is only BasedOn possibility. For example you can find that in Windows 8 there was [CompoundStyle](https://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/using-multiple-styles-on-elements-in-xaml-windows-8wp7/) component written for those needs